# How to handle systematically missing values?

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

In my situation, one of two sources is not invoked if the confidence reported by the first source is higher than a threshold and hence it is missing in some examples. How can account for such missing data?

Comment: If you have two values $(X, Y)$ with $X$ always observed and $Y$ missing if $X$ exceeds a threshold then $Y$ is missing at random because the missingness does not depend on $Y$. How you proceed is problem specific, although it's worth pointing out that if you *never* observe $Y$ when $X$ exceeds a threshold then you cannot (nonparametrically) learn the marginal distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @guy Thanks for suggesting the correction. I looked up the definition more closely and figured 'missing not at random' isn't correct for this problem.

"it's worth pointing out that if you never observe Y when X exceeds a threshold then you cannot (nonparametrically) learn the marginal distribution of Y". Can you please expand on this or point me to some resources.